# How to recover a USB hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

On accident I deleted the partition on my moms backup drive and I need to get the data back and I have no idea how to do this. its about 1TB (931GB) and I also don't have one big enough to store that much data (Though I can repurpose a drive for it) I can use both Linux and windows utility's.

Answer (score -3):

I got puran file recovery to work (for windows)

Comment: It needs more information